# Create database with UTF8 encoding

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'd want to create database with entityframework / npgsql driver with code-first approach but also UTF encoding.

In PGAdmin 3 I'm unable to change Encoding because its field is readonly

This sql is being shown in PGAdmin when I select my database

```
CREATE DATABASE db
WITH OWNER = dbuser
       ENCODING = 'LATIN2' <------------
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'pl_PL'
       LC_CTYPE = 'pl_PL'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

But I want to change it from `LATIN2` to `UTF8`

I manually tried this:

> SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'UTF8'

and

> show client_encoding

returns

> client_encoding_text
>
> UTF8

but despite that PGAdmin 3 still shows that this database has an encoding "LATIN2"

and my application is receiving an exception

> PostgresException: 22P05: the character 0xe2889e coding "UTF8" does not have an equivalent in "LATIN2"

So, how can I create db with UTF8 via Entityframework with NPSQL driver for postgre using `context.Database.EnsureCreated()`?

Comment: Use `ENCODING 'UTF8'` instead of `ENCODING = 'LATIN2'` in the statement that creates the database. That has nothing to do with .NET or EF by the way, unless the question is about database migrations and seeding

Comment: *Client* encoding as the name says, is about the encoding used to communicate with the client. It's not the database's or column data's encoding. You can't just change the encoding of an entire database that already contains data. You'd have to convert all existing text and indexes to the new encoding. Each column can have its own encoding too, which means you'd have to check and handle each column separately.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But normally I'm not using SQL to create database. I'm using ``context.Database.EnsureCreated();`` in C# and I'm curious whether it is possible to set encoding from that place or maybe in Context's ctor with options

Comment: The CREATE DATABASE statement above was not generated by Npgsql... Npgsql's EF Core provider only issues `CREATE DATABASE xxx`, optionally with a template and tablespace - but does not explicitly set the encoding. As such, the default encoding is used, which is UTF8 by default. Check again exactly who's creating your database.

Comment: @ShayRojansky I'm removing database (manually), starting my app and database is created basing on my models via ``context.Database.EnsureCreated()``